# What is the name for the image form you get you take a line segment and sweep it through a region of space?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

For instance, if you were to take a line segment and translate it along a coplanar path, then you'd get a plane.

If the path is cyclic and on that path you rotate the line segment on the axis perpendicular to the direction of the line segment, then you'd get the mobius strip.

Comment: Your question is not clear: can you be more specific about the kind of "sweeping"? In your first example, the "coplanar path" is not clear, but if you mean along a straight line you get a band, not a full plane. In your second example you get a Mobius strip only of the cycle is large enough and the segment rotates exactly one half-turn as it completes the cycle.

Comment: I'm sorry -- I meant what you suggested; the path is a straight line and the resultant form is a band. Also, the resultant form is a Mobius strip if the cycle is large enough and the segment rotates exactly one half-turn, as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't do anything *too* crazy with a line (like moving it along a space-filling curve), you will get a (part of) [ruled surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface). Two examples from Wikipedia: helicoid and hyperboloid.

[image: helicoid]

[image: hyperboloid]

Comment: Ah! Yes. Thanks!

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RuledSurface.html